# Missing right parenthesis on inner join.

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (CMEOWN.ird_no_preselection_1        AS t1
INNER JOIN CMEOWN.ird_no_preselection_1_a AS t2
ON t1.ird_number       = t2.ird_number
AND t1.location_number = t2.location_number);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not without paranthesis:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM CMEOWN.ird_no_preselection_1        AS t1
INNER JOIN CMEOWN.ird_no_preselection_1_a AS t2
ON t1.ird_number       = t2.ird_number
AND t1.location_number = t2.location_number;
```

then try this (remove `AS`es):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM CMEOWN.ird_no_preselection_1 t1
INNER JOIN CMEOWN.ird_no_preselection_1_a t2
ON t1.ird_number       = t2.ird_number
AND t1.location_number = t2.location_number;
```

Comment: That gives me 'SQL statement not properly ended'.

Comment: Don't even have to remove the parenthesis, it's just the `as` problem.  Although usually, yeah, not nesting the statement probably reads a little cleaner.  But boy is that a non-obvious error message...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse are you sure about parenthesis? They look completely wrong to me.

Comment: [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86f89/5) says it works, maybe it's just a version thing?